# Manhwa where the main character was transfered or reincarnated from his previous life

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

In this manhwa the main character was tranfered or reincarnated, and what I mostly remember is that he has some kind of skill that helps him to better adapt to any type of training. He was a sword Saint and before that he was a healing Saint, and after he was transfered and he woke up inside a broken house of some sort (I'm not sure). He picked up a piece of wood, and encountered goblins, then defeated them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you’re talking about *Shijou Saikyou no Mahou kenshi, F-Rank Boukensha ni Tensei suru*.

Starts with the last fight from his life as a swordsman and after getting transferred picks up some wood and kills some goblins just like you described.